# visualization of touch events on screen recorings

Tags: javascript, html5-video, data-visualization, touch-event

I have made an Index.html with Javascript, but now I'm stucked at visualizing the touch events on the synchronized mp4 screen recording ( The visualization should be as simple as a circle appears on the video when the area is being touched on the screen, no trail needed).

what i have now:

*1. An array of touch events, for example:*

```
{"touches":
{"location":[881.5,744],
"frame":{"origin":[0,0],
"display_size":[1024,768]}},
"timestamp":"2018-02-04T11:50:02.8560+0100",
"event":"touches",
"mediaTime":8817.9751203333344}

{"touches":
{"location":[884.5,744],
"frame":{"origin":[0,0],
"display_size":[1024,768]}},
"timestamp":"2018-02-04T11:50:06.8460+0100",
"event":"touches",
"mediaTime":8819.9706203333344}
```

*2. A synchronized mp4 screen recording.*

any tools/ideas that can simply mapping the touches onto the video? Thanks in advance for your tip!

Answer (score 0):

You have the display size, user clicks coordinates and the media which displays the background (page). 
If you don't want to modify the video to include this coordinates at right time, simply create additional layer via HTML and CSS and show the positions during video playing.

Comment: Sry i forgot to mention that the array is returned automatically after the user has imported a json logging file by a analysing function. So I mean the videos and arrays are different and randomized. Is it possible to automate the process for each arrays without modifying the video?

Comment: I decided to use heatmap.js, shows better results and yet not complicated.